# Texmaker - Where to type 'H' for help?

Tags: errors, texmaker

I'm trying to resolve an error in my latex document. The box at the bottom of texmaker says:

```
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

Where exactly do I type this? I tried typing 'H' at the end of the sentence but nothing was happening.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run tex on the commandline, then by default it *stops* at an error and gives the question mark prompt to which you can type `h` (for help) or `x` to quit or `s` to scroll through future errors without stopping etc.

Your editor (in common with most other such systems) is running tex in `\scrollmode` where tex doesn't stop on each error and acts as if you
had typed `s`. This allows TeX to finish, and the editor to parse the log file and show that display. As TeX scrolls past each error the standard message
is still printed to the log, even though interaction is not possible.

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle, how can I run tex on the commandline? I have Texmaker.

Comment: texmaker is just the editor, assuming you have pdflatex in your path then simply cd to the folder with your document and type `pdflatex myfile`  if your document is `myfile.tex`