# How do I disable scrollmode in Tex Maker?

Tags: errors, texmaker

As answered by David Carlisle in this thread:
[Texmaker - Where to type 'H' for help?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244772/texmaker-where-to-type-h-for-help/244778)

David states that `\scrollmode` is on not allowing the user to interact with the error message after the document has been compiled. How do I disable it?

Comment: I don't know that editor but there is no reason to suppose that it is possible. Many editors run tex in a non-interactive background shell that can not take user input. That is why I suggested using the commandline.

Comment: ah, so are you suggesting to circumvent the editor all together and run latex solely from the command line?

Comment: that is what I suggesd in the answer that you linked to, but as I say I have no knowledge about texmaker, it may have an interactive shell, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to respond, David, it's really appreciated. I've worked out what was causing the error message so have fixed the issue now. I have come to the conclusion that you are correct wrt TexMaker being non-interactive. I will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As @David Carlisle pointed out in the comments; I believe TexMaker runs LaTex in a non-interactive environment. If you cannot solve the error message yourself or find an adequate workaraound then try running the tex document in a different program (other than TexMaker) or, as David suggests, direct from the command line interface of your device.